# How to know strong name of GWT serialization policy at the time of host page generation?

Tags: gwt

There is an [excellent article](http://www.techhui.com/profiles/blogs/simpler-and-speedier-gwt-with) describing a way to embed GWT RPC payload into the host page. A key element is missing there is how to know Strong Name of RPC serialization policy at run time.

Strong Name is computed at the compile time, put into the client and obfurscated. Strong name is sent to the server with RPC request as [described here](http://www.gdssecurity.com/l/b/page/2/). What would you suggest to make this parameter available at the time of host page generation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have integrated GWT with spring with a custom `SerializationPolicyProvider` where I always had to rename `<strong name>.gwt.rpc` file and hard code the name in my custom `SerializationPolicyProvider` class. I got work around by looking at [GWT](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/1.6/FAQ_Server) docs. Strong Name is MD5 hash with length of 32. Each time RPC call is made to Spring based Controller's method: `public String processCall(String payload)`, I parse the payload using following code to get strong name:

```
String strongName = null;
     if(payload!=null){
         StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(payload,String.valueOf(AbstractSerializationStream.RPC_SEPARATOR_CHAR));
         while(tokens.hasMoreTokens()){
             String s = tokens.nextToken();
             if(s.length() == 32){
                 strongName = s;
                break;
             }
         }
     }
```

Then in your SerializationPolicyProvider impl class use following:
to get SerializationPolicy:

```
return SerializationPolicyLoader.loadFromStream(servletContext.getResourceAsStream(moduleBaseURL+"/"+strongName+"gwt.rpc");
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution seems to be using compiler -gen option. Get _Proxy.java from compiler output and extract SERIALIZATION_POLICY from it.